# Is the Field of View adjustable in Just Cause 3?

Tags: just-cause-3

There was a setting to adjust FOV in Just Cause 2, and it was adjustable from 1.0 to 2.0. I tried the same setting and it didn't seem to do anything for Just Cause 3. Is there any way to increase the angle?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way to increase the FOV naturally, I also don't know of any mods that would allow for it.